# Array Offset Encryption

Tags: php, arrays, offset

Right now I am developing a cryptography app and I have a problem with this one

```
$stralphabet=array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
```

As you can see the string above is a string of alphabet. I am making a caesar shift encryption, the algorithm is simple.

Count the number of string and then substitute each letter based from the position, so for example:

```
string is "AB" after encryption it would be "CD"
```

The problem is if I have the string YZ" it gives me an error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 26 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cryptographer\encrypt.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined offset: 27 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cryptographer\encrypt.php on line 19
```

Can you help me with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently are accessing `$stralphabel` without checking for edge case (i.e. `$stralp[$i+1]`). You should add some checks or use `modulo` operator, so instead of just:

```
$stralp[$i+1]
```

you'd have

```
$stralp[($i+1) % XXX]
```

where `XXX` is number of entries in your `stralp` array.

PS: this  is not even close to cryptography.

Comment: my problem is if the array is on the offset? how can i have the value back to 0 or a?

Answer (score 0):

Your array has 26 letters indexed from 0 to 25, so something is wrong with your cycle end condition.